# How to use JavaScript to parse a string with <markup> symbols

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
strdata = "<mymarkup><P>Hello world!</P>"
```

in an array. So for `strata[1][1]` that contains the above value. How can I detect the `<` characters with the substring function?

For example:

```
if (strata[1][1].substring(0,9) = "<mymarkup>") { 
  // etc...
```

Comment: When comparing you should have `===` not `=`

Comment: For parsing your markup, I would recommend looking into [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), especially the replacing functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever have to check against the same string. E.g. "<mymarkup>" its best to use maerics snippet.

However if you have to check against a lot of different strings it will get cumbersome. Here is a reusable example to check if a string starts with a given prefix.

Functional style:

```
function startsWith(str, starts){
  return str.length >= starts.length && str.substring(0, starts.length) === starts;
 }

if(startsWith(strata[1][1], '<mymarkup>')){ 
 // do something
}
```

Object-oriented style

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(starts){
    return this.length >= starts.length && this.substring(0, starts.length) === starts;
};

if(strata[1][1].startsWith('<mymarkup>')){ 
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `==` (or better `===`) operator for comparison and your example will work.  The `=` operator is for assignment and will (almost) always not yield the results you expect for a conditional.

```javascript
if (strdata[1][1].substring(0,10) === "<mymarkup>") { 
  // Ok...
```

You can also use the [string `indexOf()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to detect the `<` character:

```javascript
if (strdata[1][1].indexOf("<") > -1) {
  // Ok...
```